# not able to access index.html from url localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, express

actualy through node js server  by using express . i want to access of angular 
component . but not able to access index.jtml. it is showing error

> localhost:3000`=

I want that execute app.componenet.html attribute but not able to get
this is available in server.js

```
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const port = 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/index.html'));
});`
```

by hitting url:localhost:3000
I am expecting that out should appwork! but the actual result

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\backup\learning\MEAN\ngApp\dist\index.html'

Comment: Welcome on SO. Did you built your Angular app on your machine? Meaning, do you have the dist/ folder at the expected location?

Comment: yes I build Angular app